# Firestore: Security Rules for Querying Collection Group?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Here is my structured data:

```
Users
 - w34rj3d9d2383
   - name
   - email
   - items (sub-collection)
     - dj23jd23wkjdkl
       - name
       - notes
       - createdBy
     - 4ru328rjwiodj2309
       - name
       - notes
       - createdBy
```

Using the rules below, I am able to specify the `userId` and `itemId` to successfully subscribe to an individual item in the `items` subcollection for the authenticated user. I am also able to fetch all the items for the specified user if I don't apply a predicate.

The problem is that when I attempt to apply a predicate to the collection (see below), it doesn't return anything.

```swift
let path = "users/w34rj3d9d2383/items"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.name CONTAINS %@", name)
let collectionReference = Firestore.firestore().collection(path).filter(using: predicate)
collectionReference.addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: false) { querySnapshot, error in
    //...
}
```

Here are my security rules. How can I query over my sub collection?

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
    
    match /users/{userId}/{document=**}{
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

### Update 1: I tried the following, but it still shows permission issues:

1. Updating my reference to collection group:

```swift
let collectionReference = Firestore.firestore().collectionGroup("items").filter(using: predicate)
```

2. Adding this to my rules

```
match /{path=**}/items/{itemId} {
    allow list: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.createdBy;
    allow get: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.createdBy;
}
```

### Update 2: I got a query going, and the following rule working:

```
match /{path=**}/items/{itemId} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
}
```

This means I can fetch all items anytime I do a collection group query without a predicate. However, I want to only return items where the `resource.data.createdBy` value matches `request.auth.uid`. However, when I add this check it says resource is null.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using `whereField(...)` as shown in the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#kotlin+ktx

Comment: Mainly to keep the Firebase implementation separate from the rest of my networking layers. By not exposing FirebaseQuery or other Firebase items to my services and repos, I can more easily replace / change things later. NSPredicate makes this possible.

I think my issue atm isn't so much the filtering, as it is allowing the currently authenticated user access to only the items they created by querying collection groups. Right now, if I don't pass a filter, it returns all items (including other people's). :/

Comment: Have you tried logging `currentUser.uid` in your app before the query and checking it's correct and there are documents with that ID? Can you also share a screenshot of a document that you think should match your query?